# How to catch GTK focus state in gtkrc?

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtk2

GTK+ 2.x has the follow states: `NORMAL, PRELIGHT, ACTIVE, INSENSITIVE, SELECTED` for use in GTK themes and I can do things like...

```
bg[NORMAL] = "#f6f6f6"
```

.. to change background color when in `NORMAL` state.

Also, I can change the background image of a button (when the mouse is over it) by changing the `PRELIGHT` state image.

But I was not able to find a way to change the button background when the user cycle the focus using the TAB arrow (ie. when a dashed rectangle appears around the button). I want to do this using themes in gtkrc, is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The [RC file documentation](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html) doesn't even mention "focus", so I don't think it's possible to theme that in this way.

Comment: It's a shame gtk doesn't have such simple feature. I've searched a lot for this and found the same conclusion as you. Thank you.